# Given a class member, how can I access other members of the same class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, member

I have two classes, I'll call them "foo" and "bar". "foo" has two public members: (a string for its name and a vector of type "bar").

```
class bar {
    //not important
};

class foo {
public:
    std::string fooName;
    std::vector<bar> bars;
}
```

If I have an element of bars, how can I access and print its corresponding fooName? I'm thinking about something along these lines, but I don't know how to fill in the blank:

```
std::cout << bars[index].__________.fooName;
```

When I try googling an answer, I can only find people asking about accessing private members of other classes.

Comment: What is `bars` in your example? If this line of code is inside a member function of `foo`, then you can just write `fooName` by itself, same as you do `bars`. If it's not, then, again, what's `bars`? It would be best to show a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `std::vector` of `foo`s, with a member variable of type `bar`?

Comment: There's no easy way to do that. Instead of storing `bar`s directly in the vector, you'll need to store a `struct` which in addition to a `bar` contains a pointer to `foo`. Then you need to carefully update those pointers to make sure they stay valid if `foo` is moved or copied. This is error-prone, so if possible, consider changing the design.

Comment: You can't do that. C++ does not work this way. The only thing that can be done here would be on the order of `bar`s storing pointers to their `foo`. However this is messy, error prone, and a fertile breeding ground for bugs. You should describe the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one about getting each `bar`'s `foo`, but the problem to which you believe the solution involves getting each `bar`'s `foo`, so that's what you're asking about. Try asking the real problem.

Comment: I think OP is asking for something like `getInstance()` which is available in Java.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm trying to recreate a board game. `foo` is a continent and `bar` is a city within the continent. The board has multiple continents (`foo`), and each continent has multiple cities (`bar`). I want to be able to print the name of the continent, only given the city it holds.

Comment: Again, in the line `std::cout << bars[index] ...`, what's `bars`? Where does it come from? If it comes from an instance of `foo`, then you can get `fooName` from the same place. If it comes from elsewhere, then what reason is there to believe that a suitable `foo` exists somewhere?

Comment: You'd need to give each `bar` a pointer back to a `foo` that owns it. Or just duplicate the continent name into each city. There is no magical back-pointer built into the language; if you need one, add one to your class.

Comment: @sharkie The title of the post doesn't quite match the contents of the question. You don't even have a member of the enclosing class, but only an element of a vector which is a member of the enclosing class. This changes the potential answer from "sometimes possible but ugly and not portable" to "just not possible without design changes".

Comment: Not sure if i'm missing something but shouldn't `foo` contain a collection of `bar` objects? It makes sense to associate the `cities` with the `continent` it's associated with.

Comment: @WBuck `foo` does have a collection of `bar` objects (at least I think this is what you're asking): "`std::vector<bar> bars`"

Comment: @sharkie Ah yes you're right, I miss read your example

Comment: Food for thought: If I have an element of bars, how can I know that it came from a `foo` object? Or perhaps I should phrase that as how can *the compiler* know that it came from a `foo` object?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not totally sure if this is what you're after but if your `foo` object contains the collection of `bar` objects then you should know which `foo` objects name to print.

```
struct Bar
{ std::string name; };

struct Foo
{
    Foo( std::string fooName ) 
        : name{ std::move( fooName ) } { }

    void AddBar( Bar bar ) 
    { bars.push_back( std::move( bar ) ); }

    bool Contains( std::string_view barName ) const
    {
        return ( std::find_if( std::begin( bars ), std::end( bars ), 
            [ &barName ]( const Bar& bar ) { 

                return bar.name.compare( barName ) == 0; 
            }) != std::end( bars ) );
    }

    std::string name;
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
};

int main( )
{
    Foo foo{ "North America" };
    foo.AddBar( { "New York" } );
    foo.AddBar( { "LA" } );
    foo.AddBar( { "Toronto" } );
    foo.AddBar( { "Seattle" } );
    foo.AddBar( { "BC" } );
    foo.AddBar( { "Winnipeg" } );

    // Check if a single foo instance contains the city.
    if ( foo.Contains( "Toronto" ) )
        std::cout << "City: Toronto Continent: " << foo.name << '\n'; 

    Foo foo2{ "South America" };
    foo2.AddBar( { "Lima" } );
    foo2.AddBar( { "Santiago" } );
    foo2.AddBar( { "Salvador" } );
    foo2.AddBar( { "Fortaleza" } );
    foo2.AddBar( { "Quito" } );

    std::vector<Foo> foos{ std::move( foo ), std::move( foo2 ) };

    // Check if any foo instance contains a specific city.
    const std::string cityName{ "Toronto" };

    auto it{ std::find_if( std::begin( foos ), std::end( foos ), 
        [ &cityName ]( const Foo& foo ) { return foo.Contains( cityName ); } ) };

    if ( it != std::end( foos ) )
        std::cout << "Continent: " << it->name << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Funny how accurate the cities you used were in comparison to the one's in my board game (Spy Trackdown if you're interested). What I ended up doing, though probably not very efficient, is making a nested for-loop to scan through all of the `foo`'s `bar`s until I found a match, then returned the `foo`.

Comment: `if ( foo.Contains( "Toronto" ) )` This just runs a search by name. But the OP wrote "*if I have* ***an element*** *of bars,*", and I read that to mean that they have a `bar` element and want to figure out which `foo` it belongs to. IMHO this is different from what you propose. Suppose for example that city "London" is included in the list for both Europe and North America. It would have the same name, but different `bar` objects in each `foo`. If you only had the name, you couldn't tell which one it refers to, but a `bar` object uniquely belongs to just one `foo` continent.

Comment: @dxiv To be honest I was a little confused by the *"if I have an element of bars,"* so I looked at the `structure`'s he had and guessed. You're correct about the `London` example. You'd need some other unique identifier to ensure you get the correct `London` (like country). The `Contains` method would have to be changed to search for both city and country or something along those lines.

Comment: @WBuck Or, if the OP does indeed have (a reference/pointer to) a `bar` object known to be in a `foo::bars` vector, you could simply match by address. It would still be a linear search, though, as opposed to some "magic" direct lookup.

Comment: @dxiv I suspect (again I'm guessing) that the separate collection of `bar`'s he has are not `pointers/references` to the `bar` objects  contained in his `foo`'s. (That was an odd sentence).

Comment: @dxiv The game has no shared names between cities, so that problem won't arise. Other problems probably will eventually

Comment: @sharkie That clarification belongs into the question, not a comment. So you are basically asking how to search a list of vectors for a matching string, which is quite different from what the title and the post imply. And btw the 1/2 million people in and around [London, Ontario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London,_Ontario) could argue that they should be rightfully counted amongst North America ;-)